# Neo4j find all users who aren't followed by me

Tags: neo4j

How to find all users who aren't followed by me in NEO4J graph database.

Tried the following query:

a)

```
MATCH (u:User {username:'davidp'}) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(p) return p;
```

Output: Error.

b)

```
MATCH (a:User {username: 'rameshp'}) WHERE not ((a)--()) RETURN a;
```

Output: no records

c)

```
MATCH (a:User) WHERE not ((a)--()) RETURN a;
```

Output: few records are missed whom I'm not following.

Answer (score 1):

MATCH yourself (u) and all other users(p) and RETURN p where '(u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(p)' doesn't exist:

```
MATCH (u:User {username:'davidp'}), (p:User)
WHERE NOT (u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(p) AND p.username <> 'davidp'
RETURN p;
```

If you want just the usernames:

```
MATCH (u:User {username:'davidp'}), (p:User)
WHERE NOT (u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(p) AND p.username <> 'davidp'
RETURN p.username;
```

If you are running the query from the Neo4j Browser, ignore the cartesian Product warning since you are returning p only.

Comment: Wonderful! thank you, but it even returns the user with username davidp. How to return other users only?

Comment: You can add another filter to the WHERE clause to exclude davidp. I have updated the answer. Technically, one doesn't follow oneself :).

Comment: How to create an index on the relationship to query faster? 
Relationship: (u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(p)